# Object being recognized as null or undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror, javascript-objects, prototype, assign

I'm trying to assign housePrototype  as the prototype of House object, and followed up with this error

> Object.assign(House.prototype, this.housePrototype);
> ^ TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

What am I doing wrong?

```js
const House = {
    name: 'houseObject',
     readLocation: (location)=>{
      console.log(`house is located at ${location}`)
    }
  }

  const housePrototype = {
    readLocation: (location) => {
    console.log(`house prototype is located at ${location}`)
    }
  }

  Object.assign(House.prototype, housePrototype)
  
  House.readLocation('Malabe');
  console.log(House);
```

Comment: `House.prototype` is undefined

Comment: But https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes article saying we can set prototype in assign method as below. Can you explain please?

Comment: isn't it should be `Object.assign(House, housePrototype);`?

Comment: you've read that page wrong ... notice the code where `Object.assign(Person.prototype, personPrototype);` is used ... check what `Person` is and compare it to what `House` is

Comment: because u dont have property `prototype` in House object

Comment: @JaromandaX Person is a function and House is an abject but aren't they both supposed to have prototypes? Functions are also objects in JavaScript right?

Comment: @TimoDevs   console.log(House.__proto__) prints its prototype to the console doesn't the House.prototype does the same for regular objects? (not function objects)

Comment: `console.log({}.prototype)` vs `console.log(function() {}.prototype)` should answer your question

Comment: @JaromandaX oh wow  never realized the difference till now thank you so much

Comment: @InodUmayanga Both objects have prototypes: `Object.getPrototypeOf(House)`, `Object.getPrototypeOf(Person)`. But only the constructor function has a `.prototype` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credit goes to @JaromandaX. He explained the issue in the comments of the question.

Even though functions are Objects in JavaScript they are **NOT** identical. To access the prototype of a function `function() {}.prototype` can be used. But in the question, it is trying to access the prototype of a regular object, not a function object, which is undefined, thus the error.

```
Object.assign(House.__proto__, housePrototype);
```

With this it is possible to assign desired object to the prototype (It is not recommended to assign any variables to **proto** and it si not at all a  common pra)

The solution code would be

```js
const House = {
    name: 'houseObject',
     readLocation: (location)=>{
      console.log(`house is located at ${location}`)
    }
  }

  const housePrototype = {
    readLocation: (location) => {
    console.log(`house prototype is located at ${location}`)
    }
  }

  Object.assign(House.__proto__, housePrototype)
  
  House.readLocation('Malabe');
```

I found a complete description in following StackOverflow thread
[__proto__ VS. prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript)

Comment: No, don't do that. `House.__proto__` is `Object.prototype`, and you should absolutely not assign any properties to that.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks and I will not use __proto__  anywhere in a production code. I'll edit the answer not recommending to use it further

Answer (score -2):

Hey Bro the problem is House.prototpe because the object house has no object called prototype there are only two name and readLocation so change code to this :
from this :

```
const House = {
    name: 'houseObject',
     readLocation: (location)=>{
      console.log(`house is located at ${location}`)
    }
  }

  const housePrototype = {
    readLocation: (location) => {
    console.log(`house prototype is located at ${location}`)
    }
  }

  Object.assign(House.prototype, housePrototype)
  
  House.readLocation('Malabe');
  console.log(House);
```

to this :

```
const House = {
    name: 'houseObject',
     readLocation: (location)=>{
      console.log(`house is located at ${location}`)
    }
  }

  const housePrototype = {
    readLocation: (location) => {
    console.log(`house prototype is located at ${location}`)
    }
  }

  Object.assign(House, housePrototype)
  
  House.readLocation('Malabe');
  console.log(House);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Usefull docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#try_it

```js
const House = {
  name: 'houseObject',
  readLocation: (location)=>{
    console.log(`house is located at ${location}`)
  }
}

const housePrototype = {
  readLocation: (location) => {
    console.log(`house prototype is located at ${location}`)
  }
}

//Object.assign(target, src);
Object.assign(House, housePrototype);

House.readLocation('Malabe');
console.log(House);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).