# Accessing __proto__ on a function returns a function

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

Consider the following code :

```js
function objectFunction() {
  this.x = 2;
}
console.log(Object.keys(objectFunction));
console.log(objectFunction.__proto__, objectFunction.prototype);
```

Why am i getting a function on accessing `__proto__` property on `objectFunction` since I can't find this property in the array I got using `Object.keys(objectFunction)`  ?
Even when i call that returned function, it returns undefined.

When I tried running the above code, I got following : [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H0PR.png)
We have no keys on objectFunction, but I am able to access `__proto__`, which should not be the case. It should have returned undefined.
I know from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript) that `__proto__` is available only on instances and `prototype` on Functions or Objects.

Comment: Please, put the javascript code in a code snippet for user convenience. https://jsfiddle.net/w5sq8kcy/

Comment: See this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/9959753/13292604](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9959753/13292604). That should solve your problem.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*I know from here that `__proto__` is available only on instances and prototype on Functions or Objects*"

Comment: @Bergi see comment 1 on solution 1 on the link i mentioned

Comment: @berriz44 the code is already in a snippet.

Comment: @ShekharDangi [That comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript#comment39152761_9959753) talks only about `.prototype`. It does not say that `__proto__` is only available on instances.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I got it now. Thank you

Comment: @ShekharDangi it is not in a snippet, it is in a code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__proto__` is a non-enumerable getter on `Object.prototype` which exists in `objectFunction`'s prototype chain (`objectFunction`->`Function.prototype`->`Object.prototype`)

So you are getting `Function.prototype`

Which is a function because "The Function prototype object is specified to be a function object to ensure compatibility with ECMAScript code that was created prior to the ECMAScript 2015 specification" https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object

Comment: But what is non-enumerable getter? Also, why don't i get this property using Object.keys()?

Comment: @ShekharDangi "non-enumerable" means you won't get this property using Object.keys() ang "getter" means it's sorta a `.get__proto__()` method that is called on value acess

Comment: @ShekharDangi https://javascript.info/property-descriptors

Comment: Why i got null when i called that function and what function is that which i got when i tried accessing this property?

Comment: @ShekharDangi it's `class Obj { get __proto__(){ return Object.getPrototypeOf(this) } }` iirc.

Comment: Can you please tell me where can i look for the original JS code for any function? Like where to look for that thing like you gave?

Comment: @ShekharDangi https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto#specifications has https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__ link to spec (which you don't really ever need, but may read to understand how it works internally)

Comment: @ShekharDangi "The Function prototype object is specified to be a function object to ensure compatibility with ECMAScript code that was created prior to the ECMAScript 2015 specification" https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the references. This will definitely help me to dive deep into these things.