# what is the different between obj.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype and obj.prototype.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype

Tags: node.js

`obj.prototype.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype`

I have seen the code above sometimes, and I google about it, they say this line copy all of the EventEmitter properties to the obj. And I also see the code like this:

`obj.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype`

So I am wondering if they are the same?

---

I saw the first usage in this [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/nodejs-events-and-eventemitter/), in which the author gives the exapmle:

```
var events = require('events');
function Door(colour) {
  this.colour = colour;
  events.EventEmitter.call(this);
  this.open = function()
  {
    this.emit('open');
  }
}
Door.prototype.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype;
var frontDoor = new Door('brown');
  frontDoor.on('open', function() {
  console.log('ring ring ring');
});

frontDoor.open();
```

And he explains:

> This line: `Door.prototype.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype;` Copies all of the EventEmitter properties to the Door object.

As to the second way, I saw it in the source of [hexo](https://github.com/tommy351/hexo), in the init.js, there are code:

```
    var hexo = global.hexo = {
    get base_dir(){return baseDir},
    get public_dir(){return baseDir + 'public/'},
    get source_dir(){return baseDir + 'source/'},
    get theme_dir(){return baseDir + 'themes/' + config.theme + '/'},
    get plugin_dir(){return baseDir + 'node_modules/'},
    get script_dir(){return baseDir + 'scripts/'},
    get scaffold_dir(){return baseDir + 'scaffolds/'},
    get core_dir(){return path.dirname(dirname) + '/'},
    get lib_dir(){return dirname + '/'},
    get version(){return version},
    get env(){return env},
    get safe(){return safe},
    get debug(){return debug},
    get config(){return config},
    get extend(){return extend},
    get render(){return render},
    get util(){return util},
    get call(){return call},
    get i18n(){return i18n.i18n},
    get route(){return route},
    get db(){return db}
  };

  hexo.cache = {};

  // Inherits EventEmitter
  hexo.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype;

  // Emit "exit" event when process about to exit
  process.on('exit', function(){
    hexo.emit('exit');
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

The statements are not the same.

Rather than `obj.prototype.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype`, I'd expect to see something like `Constructor.prototype.__proto__  = events.EventEmitter.prototype`, (where `Constructor` is any kind of constructor function, so could have any name. They're often capitalized.) because the `prototype` property is typically only available on functions, and does not have any special meaning when defined as a property of a regular (non-function) object.

In other words, `obj` in first line of code given should be a (constructor) function to make sense, and it's very uncommon to see a function have such a generic variable name as `obj`.

If you'd share the source where you find the exact first statement, this may clear things up.

---

The second example is the simplest. There's no constructor involved. `hexo` is a plain object created with an object-literal. The author wants the EventEmitter methods to be available through the `hexo` method, so he assigns `EventEmitter.prototype` to the `__proto__` property, which actually changes the prototype of `hexo`.

The first code example is somewhat more complex. Here the author wants to ensure that any objects that are constructed by the `Door` function will provide access to the EventEmitter methods. Any object constructed by the Door function will get `Door.prototype` as its prototype. This particular prototype now has the EventEmitter as its prototype, so the EventEmitter functions are accessible by going two steps up the prototype chain.

"Copies all of the EventEmitter properties to the Door object." - this particular comment is misleading. No properties are copied. The only that happens is this.

```
door = new Door
door.on("open", function() { console.log("door has opened")})
```

The prototype of `door` is now `Door.prototype`. If a property (in this case `on`) is not found when trying to access it, the JS engine will look at this prototype. The prototype of `door` - `Door.prototype` - has no `on` defined either, so the JS Engine will see if `Door.prototype` has a prototype. It does, in the form of `events.EventEmitter.prototype`. And this object does have an `on` property defined.

Hope this makes things somewhat more clear. Javascript prototypical inheritance is quite tricky.

See also [Confusion about setting something.prototype.__proto__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398487/confusion-about-setting-something-prototype-proto)

Comment: I added the relative code, your reply is helpful, but according to your expiation, the code I read seems to be meaningless, could you check it for me please?

Comment: @cinvro Thanks for bringing in the actual code. As you may have recognized, the first piece of code indeed changes the object that's the prototype property of a *constructor* function. Both ways of dealing with prototypes have their unique merit/purpose. I'll try to explain further. I think you posted a very good question since it's relatively hard to answer correct and precise.

Comment: Built-in Function object's prototype and __proto__ point to the same object. Function.__proto__ === Function.prototype results in true. This is the only case that comes to my knowledge.

Comment: @Chandu I think this would make a great interview question! :)

Answer (score 2):

The `prototype` property is generally found on constructors, that is, Functions that create new objects. The `prototype` of a constructor is the object that is used as the prototype for the newly instantiated object.

The `__proto__` property of an object points to the object which was used as a prototype, when the object was first instantiated. It is non-standard, so there's no guarantee that your JavaScript engine will support it.

In your examples, you can see that they refer to `Door.prototype` and `hexo.__proto__`. The crucial difference here is that `Door` is a constructor, whereas `hexo` is an instance of an object.

However, `Door.prototype` is an instance of an object, so to get *its* prototype, you need to use `__proto__`.

In both instances, the RHS of the assignment is a constructor, so refers to `prototype`.

In summary, if you want the prototype that will be used by a constructor, use `prototype`. If you want the prototype of an instantiated object, you may be able to use `__proto__`.

In truth, you may better off just using [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf).

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

Comment: Dan, do you think you could address my comments in my answer? (I posted it as part of my answer because it got quite verbose for a mere comment box.)

Comment: the only case where obj.__proto === obj.prototype as far as I see is only this, Function.__proto__ === Function.prototype. Are there any other cases ?

Answer (score 1):

Everything in JavaScript is object. And every object, it may be a function, `{}`, `new Object()`, in JavaScript has an internal property called `[[Prototype]]`.

`[[Prototype]]` is the very reason for prototype inheritance in JavaScript. This internal property is exposed to the programmer through `__proto__`. This is a non-standard. Not all JS environments support this.

How does an object we create using constructor functions gets its `[[Prototype]]`?

Only objects whose `[[Class]]` is `Function` gets the property `prototype`. What it means is that every function declared when executed by the JS engine, it creates an object. Its `[[Class]]` is set to `Function` and a property `prototype` is attached to this function object.

By default this prototype is an object with one property `constructor` pointing to the function object.

When the above function is invoked as part of new operator like `new constructorFn()`, the JS engine creates an object, its `[[Class]]` property set to `Object` and `[[Prototype]]` property set to the object pointed to by the `[[Prototype]]` of the constructor function.

Since this new created object is of class `Object`, it does not have the `prototype` property.

In nutshell, `__proto__` exists in every object. `prototype` exists, by default, only in objects whose `[[Class]]` is `Function`. What this means is only functions (created via function statement, function expression, `Function` constructor ) will have this property.

Comment: "only functions (created via function statement , function expression , Function constructor fn) will have this property." - not entirely true. I can do `a = {prototype:"somevalue"}`, and read it out later just fine. It just doesn't have any special meaning.

Comment: I also don't think there's anything "external" about the prototype property on function objects. It's just a regular property, but one that gets special meaning as soon as the function is used as a constructor.