# How to create HTML DOM Node using Object.create() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was reading [Chromium webui source code: ui.js](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/ui/webui/resources/js/cr/ui.js?revision=290666) ( line +48, +95 ), which is using `__proto__` to morph a class into inheriting some other class.

Then I read some posts to learn `__proto__`:

- [This](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3377) and [this](http://dailyjs.com/2012/11/26/js101-proto/) says the prototype chain is internally maintained by JS VM and always exist, and you can modify it with `__proto__` pseudo property ( a accessor ).
- [Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398487/confusion-about-setting-something-prototype-proto) says by hooking up the internal prototype you can manually morph a class into derived from another class.
- [4th post](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) says some browser does not expose its internal prototype chain so you should avoid extending(using) `HTMLXXXElement.prototype` .
- Finally, [MDN said](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) `__proto__` is deprecated.

Then naturally, I thought there should be another way to create a DOM node by using `Object.create()`, then insert it into the DOM, but I tried following and failed:

```
var xt = document.querySelector('#list > div:nth-child(2)');
var list = xt.parentNode;
var o = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
o.innerHTML = 'This should be a Element Node';
list.insertBefore(o, xt);   // this line throws error
```

Chrome give me error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

I guess that I must have misunderstood HTML element Node class, and the way I use Object.create() must be wrong...  But I do not know how to phrase the question, after searching a lot I still can not find out the answer.

Do I have to use `document.createElement('a tag name')`, to create a DOM Node ?

Is it possible to create a DOM node using `Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype)`, and avoid using `__proto__` at the same time ?

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you did when you created the object is assign its `__proto__` attribute, or prototype, to the HTMLElement. That doesn't automatically make it a Node, it is still just a regular Javascript object, though its one that has access to the HTMLElement methods through its prototype chain.

You are right, you need to use createElement to create a DOM node. Its important to remember that the DOM isn't something inherent within Javascript. Its really just a special sort of 'interface' that uses Javascript for building purposes.

`document.createElement()` is a method provided by the browser specifically to build an HTML element as it conforms to the browsers DOM implementation. You theoretically *could* create a function that mimics Chromiums implementation, but it'd be a pointless effort.

`Object.create()` is a built-in Javascript function. It is there to create Javascript objects in all their forms. `document.createElement()` is not a built-in Javascript function, its provided by the browser for DOM manipulation.

Comment: Oh, I suddenly realized that I'm hitting into the wall between C++ class and JavaScript prototype in my mind.  Thanks for your patience !

Comment: Happy to help! JavaScript is undoubtedly a weird language if you're coming from a more traditional programming background.